# Can I get objects and their latest related object in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a table of Foos. Each Foo has multiple Bars. I want to return all Foos and the latest Bar for each of them. How can I do this in one PostgreSQL query?

## foos

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo1 |
| 2 | Foo2 |

## bars

| id | foo_id | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-12-02 13:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-12-02 13:30:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-12-02 14:00:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-12-02 14:30:00 |

## Expected Result

| id | name | bar.id | bar.foo_id | bar.created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo1 | 2 | 1 | 2022-12-02 13:30:00 |
| 2 | Foo2 | 4 | 2 | 2022-12-02 14:30:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the greatest per group first we need to figure

1. How to define the group, here the each `foo id` is a group
2. What is the greatest value, here the greatest value is `created_date`

To implement this use the function like `ROW_NUMBER` for this one define the partition based on `foo id` and sorting based on `created_date desc`

Which in terms of code translates to:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by f.id order by b.created_date desc)
```

```
with cte as (
select 
    f.id as foo_id, 
    f.name as foo_name, 
    b.id as bar_id, 
    b.created_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by f.id order by b.created_date desc) as RNUM 
from Foos as f join Bars as b on f.id = b.foo_id )
select 
    foo_id,
    foo_name,
    bar_id,
    created_date
from cte where RNUM = 1
```